# Digit separator in C

Tags: c, gcc

I have been able to use the digit-separator `'` in my C projects thus far. They have all been compiled with the MSVC compiler with no problems.

I have just changed to using the GCC compiler instead, which does not allow these digit-separators and throws an error, when I use them. I assume the reason is because, Visual Studio uses the same compiler for C and C++, and in C++14 (I believe), `'` digit separators are allowed.

If this is the case, is there then a digit separator usable in GCC? 
Those separators really help out a lot, when working with 64 bit register values in binary...

Comment: @CarlNorum - This is a completely different question.

Comment: Do you mean separator in printf or separator in number literals?

Comment: @krzyk - Everything points to number literals.

Comment: @CarlNorum how did you know OP is asking about ___only___ `printf()`?

Comment: Looks like it - sorry, totally misunderstood. If you want C++ features, compile as C++.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I was talking about separators in number literals (i.e. during assignments). Good idea just compiling it as C++. I guess I will have to, if there is no separator in C.

Comment: @oPolo : Since you have conceded that the question is unclear, you should edit to make it clear.  I suggest that you include a code fragment example that works in Visual Studio but not GCC - that would make it very clear and you could remove much of the *unclear* text; making the question much snappier and more likely to then get a fast answer and less comment or down-votes. The whole concept of digit separators in literal constants is relatively new to C++, and I imagine many are confused by your question - I had to look it up myself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `-std=c++1y` `gcc`/`g++` option (and have the file named like a C++ file, e.g. cpp/cxx extension) to use `'` in number literals.

Comment: -1. Question is asking for a digit separator in C, not C++. Furthermore, C23 will be [introducing `'` as a digit separator](https://thephd.dev/c-the-improvements-june-september-virtual-c-meeting).

Answer (score 8):

It's defined in [n2626](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2626.pdf), thus, you can use this feature straightly with `--std=c2x`(for gcc/clang) currently.